# Logback property value is undefined

Tags: java, logback

I have simple `logback.xml` configuration
but when i try to print the value I keep getting it's undefined.

This is my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" debug="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />

    <property name="test_key" value="this is test" />

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${"test_key"} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test" level="DEBUG">

        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>

    <root level="DEBUG">
    </root>
    <jmxConfigurator/>
</configuration>
```

No matter what I do I keep getting:

> "test_key"_IS_UNDEFINED 17:07:30.386

Why it is undefined? I did set the value.

Comment: You can try [<pattern>](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord)${"test_key"} %d{HH:mm:ss} %5p %t %c{2}: %m%n</pattern>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to the property name between quotation marks. Use `<pattern>${test_key}...` and it should work all right